# Turbolinks browser's back button issue when switching layouts in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using Turbolinks 5 in a Rails app and am having an issue with the browser's back button after clicking a link that switches from our main application.html.haml layout to another layout.  In my main layout, I have this

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload'
```

Switching to the new layout works; however, when I click the browsers back button to go back, the url changes correctly in the address bar, but the page content remains the same.

A link taking navigating back works fine, but I'd like to get the browser back/forward buttons working as expected so prevent any confusion for our users.

Anyone run into this same issue?  Any solutions?  Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have `data-turbolinks="false"` on the link that takes you to the new layout?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and it was fixed by adding the data attribute as @BoosterStage suggested:

```
<%= link_to 'Page with alternate layout', alt_page_path, data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to `active_admin.js.coffee` fixed the same issue for me:

```
#= require turbolinks
```